# Display Welcome message upon successful netcat connection

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, netcat

I have 2 terminals with title SERVER and CLIENT

I have setup a netcat listener on SERVER with below command

`nc -lvp 12345`

and from CLIENT i connect to it using

`nc 127.0.0.1 12345`

---

When ever a client connects to the server, i just want to be informed on server that a client has connected.

Comment: `nc -lvp 12345` generates an error on my system (both Linux and FreeBSD).  What netcat are you running?

Comment: netcat version is 1.10-41

Comment: Interesting. That is not the netcat installed in my Ubuntu 10.04 box, where `-p` is used only to identify the *source port* for an outgoing connection. According to the man page, "*It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the **-l** option.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(echo "Welcome"; cat) | nc -lvp 12345
```

Comment: i want to show welcome on my listener terminal, i.e. the first terminal in listen mode. But its showing welcome message on 2nd terminal :-)

Comment: @ZAZ, then you might want to update your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do. While you're at it, perhaps you could add some context so that we know the greater problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Send it with the client: `(echo "Welcome"; cat) | nc 127.0.0.1 12345`

Comment: brother it is showing me welcome message on client side, i want to show the welcome message on server side, see my edited question, thnx

Comment: @ZAZ so, use the client (not the server) to send it, as I wrote in the previous comment

Comment: @Alvaro, i giv it a try n tel u

Comment: either way, if you use the `-v` switch, `nc` will notify you when a client connects

Comment: @Alvaro its okay, there was a mistake at my end, thanks